# Vue Change state in forEach loop and if condition to update replies of any comment

Tags: vue.js, foreach

I have a State with editedIndex i want to change it in forEach loop but i am not able to call it in that loop.

i have done this code so far

```
data() {
return {
    dialog: false,
      comments: [],
      editedReply: {
        reply: null,
        comment_id: null,
        name: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).name,
        email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).email
      },
      editedIndex: -1
    };
  },
```

in above code i have added the initial state of comments which contains index of all comments
I am trying to update the replies of each comment.

```
handleEdit(reply) {
      let commentArray = this.comments;
      commentArray.forEach(function(comment) {
        comment.reply.forEach(function(item) {
          if (reply.id === item.id) {
            this.editedIndex = comment.reply.indexOf(item);
            this.editedReply = Object.assign({}, item);
          }
        });
      });
     this.dialog = true;
    },
```

from i have the list of comments in `this.comments` and ***reply*** represents the reply on which i have clicked to update.

my problem here is i am not able to call `this.editedIndex` and `this.editedReply` in if condition as i have mentioned above.
I have used comment.reply every comment contains a array of reply which you can see in below json data for comment i want to update the this json reply

json data for my comments is

```
    {
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "comment": "nice blog",
                "name": "test user",
                "email": "dhruvil@gkmit.co",
                "status": true,
                "created_at": "2020-05-28T04:36:46.797Z",
                "article": {
                    "id": 308,
                    "title": "test for comment article"
                },
                "reply": [
                    {
                        "id": 99,
                        "reply": "abcbc",
                        "name": "test2",
                        "email": "test2@mailinator.com",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-29T13:23:31.358Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "reply": "abcbc",
                        "name": "test2",
                        "email": "test2@mailinator.com",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-29T13:23:31.521Z"
                    },
               ]
         },
         {
            .......... and so on
         },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this snippet for `handleEdit` method:

```
handleEdit(reply) {
    let commentArray = this.comments;
    commentArray.forEach(comment => {
      comment.reply.forEach(item => {
        if (reply.id === item.id) {
          this.editedIndex = comment.reply.indexOf(item);
          this.editedReply = Object.assign({}, item);
        }
      });
    });
   this.dialog = true;
},
```

What's different here is I used **arrow functions** for the callbacks of `forEach` operations.